# Behat + mink + Selenium2 Get Current Browser Name

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-grid, behat, mink

How can I get the current browser name being used?  I'm using Chrome and Firefox with my feature tests going under features -> chrome, features -> firefox.  I want to take screenshots when a test fails. When I generate a screenshot, it just saves in my root dir. I want the file to be saved under the appropriate browser when I do this:

```
print_r($this->getSession()->getDriver())
```

I get that it has a private variable of browserName, but how do I access it?

```
[browserName:Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver:private] => chrome
    [desiredCapabilities:Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver:private] => Array
        (
            [browserName] => chrome
            [browser] => chrome
            [version] => 25
            [platform] => ANY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
$session = $this->getSession();
$driver = $session->getDriver();
$userAgent = $driver->evaluateScript('return navigator.userAgent');
$provider = $driver->evaluateScript('return navigator.vendor');
$browser = null;
if (preg_match('/google/i', $provider)) {
    //using chrome
    $browser = 'chrome';
} elseif (preg_match('/firefox/i',$userAgent)) {
    $browser = 'firefox';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing 
driver.executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;")

and parse the user agent string to get this information ?
This should help you get the browser name, its version, the OS information etc.,

Comment: I had to use evaluateScript instead of executeScript, since execute doesn't return data, but evaluate does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
 * Returns current browser name.
 *
 * @return string Browser name.
 */
function getBrowserName(): string
{
    return $this->getCapabilities()['browserName'];
}
```